# FirebaseDatabase: Invalid write location: /.info/connected

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

Dart implementation of https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

```
class RealtimeDatabase {
  final FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final AuthService authService = locator<AuthService>();

  Future<void> connect() async {
    // Fetch current user's ID from authentication service
    User user = authService.currentUser;
    String uid = user.uid;

    // Create reference to this user's specific status node
    // This is where we will store data about being online/offline
    var userStatusRef = db.reference().child('/status/' + uid);

    // We'll create two constants which we will write to the
    // Realtime database when this device is offline or online
    var isOfflineForDatabase = {
      'state': 'offline',
      'last_changed': ServerValue.timestamp,
    };
    var isOnlineForDatabase = {
      'state': 'online',
      'last_changed': ServerValue.timestamp,
    };

//    db.goOnline();

    // Create a ref to '.info/connected' path in Realtime db
    // This path returns true when connected and false when disconnected
    db
        .reference()
        .child('.info/connected')
        .onDisconnect()
        .set(isOfflineForDatabase)
        .then((_) => userStatusRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase));
  }
}
```

We get the following error: **Invalid write location: /.info/connected**

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database(17220): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database(17220): com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid write location: /.info/connected
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database(17220):    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritablePath(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:127)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database(17220):    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.onDisconnect(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:475)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database(17220):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:466)
...
```

What could be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this for the search engines in the future.

```
  Future<void> connect() async {
    // Fetch current user's ID from authentication service
    User user = authService.currentUser;
    String uid = user.uid;

    // Create reference to this user's specific status node
    // This is where we will store data about being online/offline
    var userStatusRef = db.reference().child('/status/' + uid);

    // We'll create two constants which we will write to the
    // Realtime database when this device is offline or online
    var isOfflineForDatabase = {
      'state': 'offline',
      'last_changed': ServerValue.timestamp,
    };
    var isOnlineForDatabase = {
      'state': 'online',
      'last_changed': ServerValue.timestamp,
    };

    // This is the correct implementation
    db.reference().child('.info/connected').onValue.listen((data) {
      if (data.snapshot.value == false) {
        return;
      }

      userStatusRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then((_) {
        userStatusRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: As the answer doesn't actually gives any clue, my mistake was probably just a bad copy/paste where, in my code, `userStatusRef ` referred to `FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('.info/connected');` which is a special node and really not what we want to write on. Switching to `.child('/status/' + uid);` resolved it.